# OpenWeatherMap API generates incorrect output

Tags: php, json, curl, weather-api, openweathermap

I am using the [**openweathermap.org**](http://openweathermap.org/) api, and it provides me incorrect output.

If I hit [**this url**](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=35d3153a253e2536f49f02fd8080dfc2&zip=94526), I get the following output :

```
"{"coord":{"lon":-121.96,"lat":37.83},"weather":[{"id":721,"main":"Haze","description":"haze","icon":"50n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":281.21,"pressure":1030,"humidity":81,"temp_min":273.15,"temp_max":285.15},"visibility":11265,"wind":{"speed":1.07,"deg":54.0019},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1454739836,"sys":{"type":1,"id":409,"message":0.0189,"country":"US","sunrise":1454771247,"sunset":1454809012},"id":5342970,"name":"Diablo","cod":200}"
```

If I call the same url via php `curl` or `file_get_contents`, I get the following output :

```
"{"coord":{"lon":-121.96,"lat":37.83},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":275.178,"pressure":1022.49,"humidity":83,"temp_min":275.178,"temp_max":275.178,"sea_level":1043.42,"grnd_level":1022.49},"wind":{"speed":1.07,"deg":356.501},"clouds":{"all":12},"dt":1454738179,"sys":{"message":0.0112,"country":"US","sunrise":1454771247,"sunset":1454809011},"id":5342970,"name":"Diablo","cod":200}"
```

Why are they different?

Comment: Where is the difference? the weather value changes instantly. It's hard to tell what is the diff if you didn't point out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. It returns the **exact** same values for longitude (`-121.96`), latitude (`37.83`), city ID (`5342970`) and city name (`Diablo`), which clearly indicates that both results represent results from the same location.

The minor differences between both results are probably caused by minor changes in the weather or results being taken from a different server or weather station (which the different values of the `base` property seem to suggest).

I wouldn't bother about these minor differences. However, I do have another concern (see my note below).

---

#### Note :

The behavior of the `zip` parameter is unreliable. When I open your URL in my browser from my location (in Belgium), I sometimes get the expected results and sometimes get this error :

```
{"cod":"404","message":"Error: Not found city"}
```

To avoid this problem, it's better to use one of the following options :

- `q` parameter, with city name and country as values :

  `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=35d3153a253e2536f49f02fd8080dfc2&q=Diablo,US`
- `id` parameter, with your city ID as a value :

  `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=35d3153a253e2536f49f02fd8080dfc2&id=5342970`
  (You can download a list of all supported city IDs [**here**](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/))
- `lat` & `lon` parameters, with your latitude and longitude as values :

  `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=35d3153a253e2536f49f02fd8080dfc2&lat=37.83&lon=-121.96`
  (You can also find the latitude and longitude of your city in [**this list of supported cities**](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/))

See [**the API docs**](http://openweathermap.org/current) for more details.